# word usage "was born to"

Tags: word-usage

This sentence is from the biography of Helen Keller.
**A baby girl was born to Captain Keller and Kate Keller.**

> What is the meaning of (to) in this sentence?
>     Does  it  means,
>   **by** or **for** ?

Answer (score 2):

No. It means *to*. The preposition makes more sense if we change *born* to *given*:

> A baby girl was given to Captain Keller and Kate Keller.

The usage is old-fashioned but it is grammatically correct. They had a baby girl.